# Entity Framework include with where clause

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am currently working on a cinema booking system for a school project and have run into a problem.

I have a Movie model which contains a list of show models(date and time for the viewing of the movie). I need to get all the movie objects that are shown on a specific date with a list containing only the Show objects which date is equal to the specific date. I have tried various ways to do it in entity but cant seem to get it to work.

Here is the Movie class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Movie
{
    [Key, Required, DataMember]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required, DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required, DataMember]
    public string Info { get; set; }

    [Required, DataMember]
    public DateTime Premiere { get; set; }

    [Required, DataMember]
    public MovieType Type { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public ICollection<Show> Shows { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string IMDBID { get; set; }
}

public enum MovieType
{
    Movie2D = 0,
    Movie3D = 1,
    KidsMovie = 2
}
```

Here is the Show class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Show
{
    [Key, Required, DataMember]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required, DataMember]
    public Guid MovieId { get; set; }

    [Required, DataMember]
    public Guid ScreenId { get; set; }

    [Required, DataMember]
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    [Required, DataMember]
    public ShowType Type { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Screen Screen { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Movie Movie { get; set; }
}

public enum ShowType
{
    Standard = 0,
    Premiere = 1,
}
```

Here is the GetMovies(DateTime date) method:

```
public List<Movie> GetMovies(DateTime date)
{
    using (EntityContext db = new EntityContext())
    {
        List<Movie> movieList = db.Movies
            .Include("Show")
            .Where(x => x.Shows.Where(x => x.DateTime.Date == date.Date)).ToList();

        return movieList;
    }
}
```

I know that this function isn't working but hope it would show what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `DateTime.Date` is not supported in Linq to Entities. You could use [`DbFunctions.TruncateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.truncatetime(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(System.Nullable%7BSystem.DateTime%7D)) static method:

```
var justDate= date.Date;
var movieList=db.Movies.Include(x=>x.Shows)
                       .Where(x => x.Shows.Any(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DateTime) == justDate))
                       .ToList();
```

### Update:

After read @Jonathan's comment I did a little research and it's true using `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` could affect the performance. You can find a detailed explanation in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32940520/does-dbfunctions-truncatetime-behave-differently-in-different-server-time-zones).

Following the same idea of @JonathanAllen and @MattJohnson, you can avoid to use that function if you do a range query instead, truncating first the Time from `date` parameter:

```
var startDate= date.Date;
var endDate= startDate.AddDays(1);
var movieList=db.Movies.Include(x=>x.Shows)
                       .Where(x => x.Shows.Any(x =>x.DateTime >= startDate && x.DateTime < endDate)
                       .ToList();
```

Comment: That's going to be really, really slow. Your database can't use indexes if you apply a function to the column you are searching against.

Comment: Thanks.. It is working now. I have only shows tuples with a DateTime on 1st and 2nd december in the database, but i get all the movie tubles out whenever i choose any date in december. It should only get some movies out when i choose 1st or 2nd december

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
public List<Movie> GetMovies(DateTime date)
{
    using (EntityContext db = new EntityContext())
    {
        List<Movie> movieList = db.Movies.Include("Show")
            .Where(x => x.Shows.Any(x => x.DateTime.Date == date.Date));

        return movieList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My request good working with All() method.

```
model.ReferenceList = db.JournalCardReference.OrderBy(a => a.orderF)
 .Include(x => x.JournalCardField)
  .Where(x => x.JournalCardField
    .All(f => f.deleted == null || f.deleted != true)).ToList();
```